# Using memcache as assession storage for multiple sites

Tags: session, memcached

I have a server hosting one that stores sessions in memcached.

I want to host a second one and I am thinking if there is going to be a problem if I use the same memcached server to store the sessions of this 2nd site as well.

Am I going to have conflicts with the session ids?
Is it possible that the session id generated for one site matches one generated for the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible that your IDs clash, e.g. in tomcat the session id is only unique in one context.
But if you're setting and getting the sessionID from memcache yourself, you could easily add a prefix to the IDs. Or if this is a module of some kind, it may be configurable to use prefixes.

Comment: Hi. I am actually using php. I wonder how hosting companies cope with such situations. Maybe php creates session ids based on some site variable as well

Comment: Furthermore, I am not handling the session generation. Php does it through memcache client

Comment: Using php you should be able to locate the code that serializes/deserialize the sessions into memcache and change it for you need.